# How does one create a lean project and have mathlib import work when not creating the lean project at the $HOME directory?

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-mathlib, lean-community

I want to create a lean project inside another folder besides the `$HOME` folder. So I was going through [the official Creating a Lean project](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html#creating-a-lean-project) instructions on how to create a Lean Project, but it only works (i.e., the import to mathlib) only works if I do the instruction on $HOME.

So for example the instructions say:

> Go to a folder where you want to create a project in a subfolder my_project, and type lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math.

but when "go to a folder" is anything but the root it doesn't work.

I wrote a bash file for what the instructions say,

1. one were it works (the one at $HOME) and
2. one that doesn't work (when I try to create the lean project not at $HOME):

##### Project Creation works when doing instructions at `$HOME`

```bash
# -- Go to a folder where you want to create a project in a subfolder my_project, and type lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math.
cd $HOME
lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math
# if you get an error message saying lake is an unknown command and you have not logged in since you installed Lean, then you may need to first type 
# source ~/.profile or source ~/.bash_profile
# - Go inside the my_project folder and type lake update, then lake exe cache get and then mkdir MyProject.
cd my_project
lake update 
lake exe cache get
mkdir MyProject
# Your Lean code should now be put inside files with extension .lean living in my_project/MyProject/ or a subfolder thereof.
cd MyProject
touch Test.lean
echo 'import Mathlib.Topology.Basic\n\n#check TopologicalSpace' > Test.lean
```

##### Project Creation fails anywhere else e.g., inside a `$HOME/entire_project_root`

```bash
mkdir $HOME/entire_project_root
# -- Go to a folder where you want to create a project in a subfolder my_project, and type lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math.
cd $HOME/entire_project_root
lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math
# if you get an error message saying lake is an unknown command and you have not logged in since you installed Lean, then you may need to first type 
# source ~/.profile or source ~/.bash_profile
# - Go inside the my_project folder and type lake update, then lake exe cache get and then mkdir MyProject.
cd my_project
lake update 
lake exe cache get
mkdir MyProject
# Your Lean code should now be put inside files with extension .lean living in my_project/MyProject/ or a subfolder thereof.
cd MyProject
touch Test.lean
echo 'import Mathlib.Topology.Basic\n\n#check TopologicalSpace' > Test.lean
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

The error message is:

```
Test.lean:1:0
unknown package 'Mathlib'
```

[image]

---

##### Comment on version 2023-02-04

> @FrançoisG.Dorais quoting the official instructions/documentation: `Do not worry about the date in the previous command, it ensures you will use a sufficiently recent version of lake but has no impact on the version of lean your project will use`  https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html#creating-a-lean-project so idk, I'm just reading them and following what the lean maintainers tell me to do. I agree with you at first glance.

Comment: Your project is in `my_project` not in `MyProject`.

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to force an old Lean version, 2023-02-04 is over a year old!

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais quoting the official instructions/documentation: `Do not worry about the date in the previous command, it ensures you will use a sufficiently recent version of lake but has no impact on the version of lean your project will use`  https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html#creating-a-lean-project so idk, I'm just reading them and following what the lean maintainers tell me to do. I agree with you at first glance.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais my understanding is that there are 3 folders (very confusing). The first folder is the root (for me `$HOME` in the example that actually works) where the lean project will be called `my_project` in my example. That folder will have a bunch of lean files like `.lake`, `lakefile.lean`, `lean-toolchain` etc. Then inside `my_folder` there will be the folder where the actual lean src code will be. That is the third folder called `MyProject`. This is the structure if I understand the official instructions correctly

Comment: official instructions I am following https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html#creating-a-lean-project and details in question of exact commands I ran in my local mac computer

Comment: say that I git clone my project. So it pulls `my_project`. However, if I run `lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math` it complains that `my_project` already exists. How do I make sure to setup matlib again for `my_project` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates that you are opening VS Code in `$HOME`. You need to open the root directory of the project folder instead. For example on the command line you need to run `code .` in the directory `$HOME/entire_project_root/my_project`, and in point-and-click VS Code you need to go to File -> Open Folder -> (open the folder called `my_project`). Then the imports will work.

The reason is that VS Code looks for information about which versions of things like Lean and Mathlib to use in any given project, in the system config files for the project, which it expects to find in the directory which you've opened in VS Code. Mathlib typically updates about 20 times per day right now, so two distinct projects which depend on mathlib will with very high probability use distinct versions of mathlib.

Observe the subtle difference between my screenshot and yours at the top:

[image]

Comment: Mysterious. I'm not opening vscode from the terminal. I'm just clicking the icon and then creating a workspace by adding the root folder. Is there a solution where it doesn't require me to open vscode from some weird directory? e.g., can I tell vscode where the path to lean is or something or my lean "env" just like I'd do with python pointing to a conda env?

Comment: what is this `the system config files for the project`? Can I edit this?

Comment: note, this answer also complicates my workflow because I will be using the ssh extension of vscode (and I can't do `code $HOME/proj_path` since there isn't vscode in the remote servers) and developing lean in remote servers. So I think it's needed for me to know precisely what the issue is so I can decide what the solution is besides locally opening the lean project that way. I'd like to be able to see all my lean, python, bash etc file in the root of my directory structure and have vscode's lean work properly. Btw, thanks for the help!

Comment: Click the icon and then use "file" -> "open folder" and open the project folder, not the root folder. If you need more precise help then you should just ask on the Lean Zulip. VS Code needs to know which version of Lean and mathlib you're using.

Comment: thank you Kevin! Definitively tried **Click the icon and then use "file" -> "open folder" and open the project folder, not the root folder. ** but I think I needed to restart vscode. I think vscode might get confused if there is already a Lean server running and at the same time from vscode's integrated terminal I start trying to set up a project. Not sure how exactly the vscode knows "where Lean is" and the respective "lean environments" but for now restarting and opening as you suggested worked. If you know where to read about the above question it would be appreciated! (I come from python)

Comment: also, it is confusing to me why the lean projects are setup as `my_project/MyProject/Test.lean` in the example. So which project is someone suppose to open? `my_project` or `MyProject`? I know now it's `my_project` but this seems to me to be a confusing way to setup lean projects.

Comment: say that I git clone my project. So it pulls `my_project`. However, if I run `lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math` it complains that `my_project` already exists. How do I make sure to setup matlib again for `my_project` in this case?

Comment: ok now there is a new error: `error: 'lean_src_proj2/' does not have a commit checked out` so basically, lean really wants my root folder to be a lean project. No matter what.

Comment: I also noticed I have to cd `lean_src_proj` and `rm -rf .git` for me to push the code from lean there.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to find what I did. I don't exactly know how Lean & vscode are setup such that vscode knows the path to the right Lean4 toolchain (e.g., compiler etc.), the "Lean env for the libraries", etc.,  but what I did is what Kevin suggested:

1. **Click the icon and then use "file" -> "open folder" and open the project folder, not the root folder.** If you need more precise help then you should just ask on the Lean Zulip. VS Code needs to know which version of Lean and mathlib you're using [Kevin B.]. In particular open `my_project` [from the Lean code example that (confusingly) has `my_project/MyProject/Test.lean`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/project.html#creating-a-lean-project).
2. if it doesn't work r**estart (update) vscode**. That seemed to work for me. Perhaps setting up the project from the vscode intergrated terminal confuses vscode.

This is the code I ran:

```bash
# -- Go to a folder where you want to create a project in a subfolder my_project, and type lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math.
cd $HOME
lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math
# if you get an error message saying lake is an unknown command and you have not logged in since you installed Lean, then you may need to first type 
# source ~/.profile or source ~/.bash_profile
# - Go inside the my_project folder and type lake update, then lake exe cache get and then mkdir MyProject.
cd my_project
lake update 
lake exe cache get
mkdir MyProject
# Your Lean code should now be put inside files with extension .lean living in my_project/MyProject/ or a subfolder thereof.
cd MyProject
echo 'import Mathlib.Topology.Basic\n\n#check TopologicalSpace' > Test.lean
```

You will likely also have to go to the `lean_src_proj` and `rm -rf .git` if you want to git push the lean project code. For some reason lake create a git repo for you.

Comment: say that I git clone my project. So it pulls `my_project`. However, if I run `lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math` it complains that `my_project` already exists. How do I make sure to setup matlib again for `my_project` in this case?

Comment: I also noticed I have to cd lean_src_proj and rm -rf .git for me to push the code from lean there.